# NullPointer exception in ContextWrapper

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-context

I have a class called FileGeneration that extends Activity
In FileGeneration I have a method called

```
protected OutputStream openAndWriteFile() {

   // Set the Context-mode
   int cxt = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

   // Check if we are not going to clear the file and the file exists
   if (!clearFile && (new File(this.fileName)).exists()) {

      // Append to the file
      cxt = Context.MODE_APPEND;
   }

   // Try to open the file to write to
   try {

      // Open the File using the Context
      this.os = openFileOutput(this.fileName, cxt);

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }

   // Return the OutputStream
   return this.os;
}
```

And I get this output in Logcat

```
06-08 15:31:43.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2850): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-08 15:31:43.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2850):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)
06-08 15:31:43.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2850):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)
06-08 15:31:43.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2850):    at dataconnection.FileGeneration.openAndWriteFile(FileGeneration.java:278)
```

Line 278 in the class is

```
this.os = openFileOutput(this.fileName, cxt);
```

But when I just print the method with the paramters out in Logcat it says

```
openFileOutput(Preferences.xml, 1);
```

The file does not exist, but openFileOutput says it will create it, if it does not exist

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with `(new ContextWrapper(ctx)).openFileOutput(this.fileName, cxt)`

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a test to see if `this.filename == null`, and output the result using the `Log.d(String,String)` method.

Comment: I have tried this by using Log.d("ProgramName", "openFileOutput(" + this.fileName + ", " + cxt + ")"); 
And that gave the output in the question